# Laravel routing by looping through array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use the Route::get method to setup the URL structure for my application without repeating Route::get for each item. I am doing this with a foreach loop as follows:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
$pages = array('about', 'contact', 'faqs');  
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    Route::get($page, function () {
        return view($page);
    });
}
```

When run I come across the error: "Undefined variable: page". Although I have worked much with procedural PHP, and PHP within CMSs, I am fairly new to Laravel. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$page` variable is not in the scope of anonymous function [A] where you defined what given route should respond with. Code below has `use ($page)` added so that variable can be accessed.

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
$pages = array('about', 'contact', 'faqs');  
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    Route::get($page, function () use ($page) { // [A] 
        return view($page);
    }); 
}
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you can have some follow-up read about nuances of this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

you can do by `where` method

```
$pages = array('about', 'contact', 'faqs');  
Route::get('/{page}',function($page) {
    return   view($page);
})->where('page',implode('|',$pages));
```